# how to safely initialize a dataclass based on a dict with unexpected keys?

Tags: python, html

I'd like to initialize A from a dict which can contain unexpected keys. I'd like to initialize with the given, known keys and ignore the rest

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: int

a1 = A(**{'a': 'Foo', 'b': 123})  # works
a2 = A(**{'a': 'Foo', 'b': 123, 'c': 'unexpected'})  # raises TypeError
```

Is there a Python feature that I'm missing or do I have to filter the dict upfront?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the `dataclasses.fields` function with a classmethod.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields


@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: int

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: dict) -> "A":
        field_names = {field.name for field in fields(cls)}
        return cls(**{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in field_names})

a1 = A.from_dict({'a': 'Foo', 'b': 123})
a2 = A.from_dict({'a': 'Foo', 'b': 123, 'c': 'unexpected, but who cares?'})
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace built-in `dataclass` with `pydantic` implementation

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: int

a1 = A(**{'a': 'Foo', 'b': 123}) # works
a2 = A(**{'a': 'Foo', 'b': 123, 'c': 'unexpected'})
print(a1, a2) # prints A(a='Foo', b=123) A(a='Foo', b=123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is easier than I expected...

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(init=False)
class A:
    a: str
    b: int

    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, **therest):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

The `init=False` parameter of the dataclass decorator indicates you will provide a custom `__init__` function. Docs [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#custom-init-method)